# How to use two backgrounds for one element and put second background on top of first?

Tags: webkit, css, semantic-markup

In a project I need to make headings like this and I want to use with less image and markup because Texture will be the same but Gradient are different in different sections.

I have 3 things in heading.

1. Heading text
2. A texture over the gradient and
   under the heading text
3. A gradient behind the texture

like this in a combined form

[image]

I'm only considering Web-Kit based browsers. I can make gradient with CSS. I can put heading text and can add shadow in css.

I want to make this thing without using any image or less image. So question is, Is it possible to make texture in css and If it's not possible then what is the best Semantic way to achive this heading with one transparent texture image?

I want to make this with this code

```
<h1> Heading Level 1 </h1>
```

So using CSS can i use 2 backgrounds 1) gradient made by css and 2) on the top of the gradient I want to put transparent image of texture with `repeat-x`

And If we can't put background in layers then  what other way you would suggest?

Will I have to use with extra `span` and `z-index`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only care about recent WebKit browsers, you can use CSS3's [multiple backgrounds](http://css-tricks.com/stacking-order-of-multiple-backgrounds/):

See: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/xCnZs/

**HTML:**

```
<h1>Heading Level 1</h1>
```

**CSS:**

```
h1 {
    font: 42px/1 Georgia, serif; 
    color: #fff;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 12px;

    background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgOES.png) top left repeat, -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#6db3f2), color-stop(50%,#54a3ee), color-stop(51%,#3690f0), color-stop(100%,#1e69de));

    text-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #000;
}
```

---

I used Photoshop to quickly make this image:

[image]

It's a transparent `.png` with just a random texture on it. It doesn't tile very well, but I didn't try to make it do so; it was just to show the concept.

It would be very difficult to make the texture with pure CSS. Though probably not impossible.

Comment: Saved me the typing, this is what I was going to recommend.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I'm going to check you example on Android Browser. By the way after looking at this http://leaverou.me/css3patterns/ I thought it  would be possible to make texture which I want.

Comment: That's an impressive gallery of gradient patterns. I saw some of her [earlier stuff](http://leaverou.me/2010/12/checkered-stripes-other-background-patterns-with-css3-gradients/). Those patterns take a while to think out and make, so it's probably out of the scope of this question. Perhaps you could make a new question with a link to that gallery, and ask if it's possible to make the exact pattern you want to make with CSS3 gradients. Lastly, I have no experience with the Android Browser, but I know it's WebKit based, so it should also work there.

Comment: OK , But one more question instead of using texture image as an image can i put as a data URI.?

Comment: Yes, that will work. Once you've made your texture, you can use [a tool like this](http://www.dopiaza.org/tools/datauri/) to create it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using embedded elements. Don't use a span because spans are inline elements and you'll have to make them display:block to get the correct overlay. I'd but the gradient in the outer-most element and your transparent texture inside it. Semantically your probably should have a div on the outside with you h1 inside it like so.

```
<div class="gradient">
    <h1 class="texture">Heading Level 1</h1>
</div>
```

Good news! You don't have to worry about only going webkit for the gradients.

```
    .gradient { background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#cfcdd2), to(#fff)); 
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #cfcdd2,  #fff); 
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#cfcdd2', endColorstr='#000000'); }
    .texture { background: url('myimage.png'); }
```

The above code will give you a gray to white gradient (top to bottom) just change out the colors with your colorscheme. It works in most browsers (not ie7 but yes ie8).

I'll be happy to help further if you need advice.