# How to make transparent texture pattern using CSS3?

Tags: webkit, css, mobile-webkit

For example like this
[image] it's transparent .png

Currently I use this transparent png and I'm fine with that but I'm just curious if it's also possible with CSS3 (on Web-kit browsers)

I saw this Pattern Gallery http://leaverou.me/css3patterns/ **but** it's for patterns.

Comment: For what it's worth, this question is a spin-off from this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5734717/405015

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is no css way of doing this. The CSS3 patterns you're linking to are interesting, but they hack the gradient functionality in order to produce some interesting patterns. With noise it's more difficult, because the data is random and pixel intensive.

I'm afraid I'm going to start with the typical "there's a jQuery plugin for that..." and  in this case it's http://rappdaniel.com/noisy/. The JS generates a [Data URI background image](http://css-tricks.com/data-uris/).